# Deploying CKEditor into SharePoint

Tags: wss-3.0, web-part

Is it possible to integrate [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) with SharePoint (WSS 3.0)? Could it be possible with Visual Studio and deploying as a Web Part??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick Tip:  Search google for Sharepoint FCKEditor or Sharepoint TinyMCE for other ideas on how to do this.  Here are a couple of pointers:

Web Part: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/FckEditorSharepoint.aspx
Custom Field Type: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/FckEditorSharepoint2.aspx

Please note that there are some sites out there (such as http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=138534 and http://www.andypemberton.com/captech/integrating-tinymce-with-sharepoint-moss-2007/) that would have you edit the OOTB javascript files and thus replace the default WYSIWYG editor with CKEditor (or a similar one).  I would recommend against that, because your changes could be quickly overwritten at the next service pack from Microsoft, and you would have to make sure that you make the change for every web server you set up.

Rather, create a solution with a feature that:
- creates a custom field type as a feature and make that field type available across your sharepoint farm.  Then, when you create a content type, instead of adding the Rich Content field type (with the built in WYSIWYG editor), use your custom Rich Content field type.  This content type could then be used in any list anywhere on your farm.
- Or, if you need to develop a a web part with CKEditor in it somewhere, set up CKEditor the same you would for other .Net solutions using CKEditor (putting the resource files under _layouts somewhere)

```
Tim
```

Answer (score 0):

It took some time, but here it is ;) [CKEditor for SharePoint](http://ckeditor.com/sharepoint)

Easy to install and upgrade, compatible with SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010. 
CKFinder is included.

Fully functional 30 days trial version is available.